# Sigma notation, changing limits

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to understand the proof for a nested loop algorithm and there is only one step that has me scratching my head. The algorithm is represented by:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i}\sum_{k=j}^{i+j}1
$$

And the right hand term is decomposed into:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i}i+j-j+1=
$$

I understand that:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n1
$$

Which explains:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{i+j}=i+j
$$

But I do not understand how the top section reduces to $-j+1$.

Or am I totally missing the point? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any sum $$\sum_{k=\textrm{start}}^{\textrm{end}}\textrm{term}_k$$ has (end-start+1) terms.

In this case, it is $\underbrace{(i+j)}_{\textrm{end}}-\underbrace{(j)}_{\textrm{start}}+1 = i+1$.

**Addendum:** To see that the first statement is true, just note that
$$\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{\textrm{end}}\textrm{term}_k}_{\textrm{end}\textrm{ terms}} = \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{\textrm{start}-1}\textrm{term}_k}_{\textrm{start}-1\textrm{ terms}} + \sum_{k=\textrm{start}}^{\textrm{end}}\textrm{term}_k$$
so that
$$\sum_{k=\textrm{start}}^{\textrm{end}}\textrm{term}_k = \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{\textrm{end}}\textrm{term}_k}_{\textrm{end}\textrm{ terms}} - \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{\textrm{start}-1}\textrm{term}_k}_{\textrm{start}-1\textrm{ terms}}$$

with the result that, after canceling all terms from the rightmost sum, there remain only $$\textrm{end}-(\textrm{start}-1) =\boxed{\textrm{end}-\textrm{start}+1}$$
terms.

Answer (score 2):

The step in question is

$$\sum_{k=j}^{i+j}1=i+j-j+1=i+1\;.$$

Since each term of the sum is $1$, the sum is simply the number of values of $k$ in the interval from $j$ through $i+j$. The interval from $1$ through $i+j$ contains $i+j$ integers; from this we have to subtract the $j-1$ integers in the interval from $1$ through $j-1$, since we want only the integers from $j$ through $i+j$. That leaves us with

$$(i+j)-(j-1)=i+j-j+1=i+1$$

values through which $k$ runs. Each of them contributes $1$ to the sum, so the total is $i+1$.